# Calculation of Power Transformers

Tags: power, transformer, step-down, calculation

I'm calculating transformers very roughly, with some approximate equations that I found on the internet, they are working perfectly but I'm supposing that they are oversized... They are power transformers with a frequency of 50hz, lets say that they goes between 10A to 60A, and 12V to 48V.

- I will let you as an example one calculation for a transformer that I done before
  [image]

And then for the diameter or section of the copper wire, I search in the AWG table, that give me the maximum current for a wire.

- Of course this are not very accurate calculus, but until now they do their job... I want if you can tell me a good way of calculating these transformers, so I can squeeze to the maximum the power of it, I don't want to waste a lot of copper, core size, etc.